# Does Keycloak API contain any method to evaluate user permissions for the specified resource?

Tags: api, keycloak

As I can see it is possible to evaluate user permissions for a specific resource via KeyCloak admin console:
client->authorization -> Evaluate.

Is there any endpoint in KeyCloak Rest API, which allows do the same programmaticaly?

Comment: you got any option ?

Comment: actually, it was quite a lot of time ago, but as I remember, I stopped on the next option:
 - received JWT token from keycloak
 - parse this token and got information about the user's roles.
 - also I had a JSON config file that contains information about which roles are required for some actions, and role names (or ids) were the same as we created in keycloak.
so, it looks like duplicating role names in keycloak and website's backend, but I haven't found any option how to send a direct request to keycloak to evaluate user roles.